# repetir consultas mientras haya respuesta con angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Necesito realizar peticiones al servidor hasta que este me este enviando contenido en la respuesta, esta configurado para enviar, por ejemplo 10 items en cada respuesta, y como tengo paginacion en la proxima peticion vendran los proximos 10, lo que quiero es un loop de peticiones mientras haya items en la respuesta. tengo lo siguiente:

```
     export class HerramientasComponent implements OnInit {

  productos: any;
  existe = true;
  constructor(private tiendaService: TiendaService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    
    while (this.existe) {
      this.tiendaService.actProductosTienda(1).subscribe((resp) => {
        this.productos = resp;
        
        if (this.productos.length !== 0) {
          this.existe = true;
          console.log('todavia hay');          
        }else{
          this.existe = false;
        }
        console.log(this.existe);
        
      }); 
    }   
  }

}
```

aunque por el momento el valor de la pagina esta estatico eso ira iterando un valor desde la vista, pero el programa se me "crashea" cuando lo ejecuto, probablemente por demasiadas peticiones al servidor.

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese `while` es prácticamente infinito. El problema es que no hay una espera entre petición y petición. Una vez hace la *request*, no espera a la respuesta y ya va con la siguiente iteración.

Para tener el `while` de forma más sana, convierte el `Observable<>` a `Promise<>` para poder "awaitearlo".

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loop();
}

async loop() {
    const get = () => this.tiendaService.actProductosTienda(1);

    while(this.exists) {
        const response = await get().toPromise();
        // Ahora sí se puede evaluar this.existe para la siguiente
        // iteración del bucle.
    }
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aprendi algo nuevo y bastante util.